# Can somebody help me understand "for" functions?

Tags: r

For a homework question I have the following code:

Could someone explain me what is happening in the code, and why it results in 22?

```
k <- 1    
for (i in 1:3){    
  k <- k + 1  
  for (j in 1:2){
    k = k * j
  }
}
```

Comment: just follow the loop and write down the value of `k` for each step...

Comment: As a general rule, you can understand what is happening in a loop with the print command.  , so print(k) strategically placed will show you what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to understand how loops work in any programming language is to follow, step by step what it is doing.

Here a simple example of how you can "debug" in paper. This could be useful in the future.

The table below represents each iteration of your loops and the values of each operation.

You should read it in this way:

1. Initially k = 1;
2. In the first iteration of the outer loop k becomes the current value of k (1) + 1, so k = 2.
3. Then the inner loop makes its first iteration, then j = 1 and k = k (2) * j (1), so k = 2
4. Then the second iteration of inner loop, j becomes 2 and k is still 2, so k = k (2) * j (2) so k = 4
5. Then returns to the outer loop where i becomes 2 and k = k (4) + 1 => k = 5
6. Then start again the inner loop (repeat steps 3 and 4)

and repeat until i is 3.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard! This really made me understand how for loops work.

Answer (score 2):

Let's debug your code line by line :
First :

```
     k <- 1    // K = 1
        for (i in 1:3){ // all the content of this loop will be repeated 3 times because i is between 1 and 3 ( 1,2,3 ) = ( i=1, i=2 and i=3)
        //First time with: i=1
        k <- k+1 // K = 1 + 1 = 2
        for (j in 1:2){ // all the content of this loop will be repeated 2 times ( with : j=1 and j=2)
            //First time with j=1:
        k <- k*j // k = 2*1 = 2
            //Second time with j=2:
        k <- k*j // k=2*2 = 4
}
}
        //Second time with: i=2
        k <- k+1 // K = 4 + 1 = 5
        for (j in 1:2){ // all the content of this loop will be repeated 2 times ( with : j=1 and j=2)
            //First time with j=1:
        k <- k*j // k = 5*1
            //Second time with j=2:
        k <- k*j // k=5*2 = 10
}
}
        //Third time with: i=3 - the last one because i is between 1 and 3 ( 1,2,3 ) 
            k <- k+1 // K = 10 + 1 = 11
            for (j in 1:2){ // all the content of this loop will be repeated 2 times ( with : j=1 and j=2)
           //First time with j=1:
            k <- k*j // k = 11*1
           //Second time with j=2:
            k <- k*j // k=11*2 = 22
    }
    }
```

The idea behind using "for" is that you want to repeat the code inside the loop a number of time depending on a condition, let's take a simple exemple: 
I want to print ten "hello" :

```
for ( i in 1:10 ){
 print "hello";
}
```

let's complicate things a little bit, if I modify the code :

```
for ( i in 1:10 ){
 print "hello";
 i <- 11;
}
```

The ouput of this code will be only 1 "Hello" because "i" = 11 and 11 isn't between 1 and 10 - for i in 1:10 -

Answer (score 0):

Add `print` statements to your loop. This is an okay way to debug and an excellent way to see what's going on. If you run this, I think it will help you understand.

```
k <- 1    
for (i in 1:3){    
  print(sprintf("Outer loop: i = %s, k = %s", i, k))
  k <- k + 1
  print(sprintf("Added one, now k = %s", k))
  for (j in 1:2){
    print(sprintf("  Inner loop: j = %s, k = %s", j, k))
    k = k * j
    print(sprintf("  Multiplied, now k = %s", k))
  }
}
```

This will print:

```
[1] "Outer loop: i = 1, k = 1"
[1] "Added one, now k = 2"
[1] "  Inner loop: j = 1, k = 2"
[1] "  Multiplied, now k = 2"
[1] "  Inner loop: j = 2, k = 2"
[1] "  Multiplied, now k = 4"
[1] "Outer loop: i = 2, k = 4"
[1] "Added one, now k = 5"
[1] "  Inner loop: j = 1, k = 5"
[1] "  Multiplied, now k = 5"
[1] "  Inner loop: j = 2, k = 5"
[1] "  Multiplied, now k = 10"
[1] "Outer loop: i = 3, k = 10"
[1] "Added one, now k = 11"
[1] "  Inner loop: j = 1, k = 11"
[1] "  Multiplied, now k = 11"
[1] "  Inner loop: j = 2, k = 11"
[1] "  Multiplied, now k = 22"
```

This is very thorough - good for a first time. In the future, you can save time with simpler `print` statements.

This also highlights that what the *inner* (`j`) loop does is multiply by `1`, then multiply by `2`. The net effect of the inner loop is just to multiply `k` by 2, so we could do all the same (meaningful) operations with a single loop:

```
k <- 1    
for (i in 1:3){    
  k <- k + 1
  k <- k * 2 ## equivalent to inner loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning you have got a variable called k with the value of 1.
k=1

To get the result of 22 the first for-loop should end at 4 instead of 3. It may be possible that I’m wrong since I’m not sure if there are variations between programming languages.

The first for-loop takes k iterates from 1 to 4 and adds it to your variable ‚k‘.

The second takes the new k and multiplies it first by 1 and then by 2.

I hope the following code helps you understanding it.

```
k=1
1. For-loop (1:4) 
k = 1 + 1   // k = 2 
k = 2 + 2  // k = 4 
k = 4 + 3   // k = 7 
k = 7 + 4    // k = 11

k=11
2. For-loop (1:2) 
k = k * 1   // k = 11 
k = k * 2   // k = 22

 k = 22
```

Comment: You seem to have missed that the for loops are *nested*. The outer loop adds `1` each time to `k`, not `i` as in your code. But more importantly the inner loop happens *every time* the outer loop does.