# For-Loop ist doing weird things

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, exception, foreach

My For-Loop ist doing weird things.
When I debug my programm, the count of the loop is after the 4rd loop equals 0, after that it starts again.

If I don't debug my programm I'm getting an Stackoverflow-Exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gegnerischeFigurenn.Count; i++)
{
                gegnerischeAngriffsfelderr.AddRange(GetAvailableFields(gegnerischeFigurenn[i], schachbrett));
                Console.WriteLine("Count: " + i);
}
```

the console output is:

```
Count: 0
Count: 1
Count: 2
Count: 3
Count: 0
Count: 1
Count: 2
Count: 3
Count: 0
Count: 1 ......
```

the result is an stackoverflow exeption if I don't debug the programm and else an wrong number increment of my count.

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting. Is it the repeating that concerns you, or that _"the count of the loop is after the 4rd loop equals 0"_?

Comment: You can use this approach to debug your code and understand where the error is coming from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54483926/4822855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be because your method is calling itself from within itself (recursive call). If you were to share more of your code around the for-loop, that may be helpful but check for anywhere within your method which makes a reference to itself. This [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2011/11/04/how-to-create-a-stackoverflowexception-and-how-to-figure-out-where-it-is-happening/) explains how stackoverflow exceptions occur so may be helpful for you.

Comment: I wouldn't simply say "likely".  The stack overflow is a dead giveaway.  It's extremely hard to get one of those in C# other than recursion gone wild.